# how to de-activate gradient tool in gimp to draw solid lines

Tags: gimp, gradient, stroke

I want to draw straight solid lines in Gimp but whenever I hold shift and create a straight line, the end is faded. I want to deactive this gradient effect but don't know how. Even if I set the front and back colours the same there remains a gradient. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Could you please add an example? What tool do you use to draw the line?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Dynamics" option for the tool, and set that to "Dynamics off" (likely says "Gradient" currently).